# A way to compile C to LLVM IR and have it generate i1 types

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I'm writing some C and compiling it to LLVM IR to serve as library code for a higher-level language I'm implementing. The LLVM conditional instructions require a one-bit value (type `i1`), but in C there's nothing smaller than a byte, so `bool`s compile to `i8`.

Is there a straightforward way to make clang generate the `i1` type (either from `bool` or some other defined type) when I compile the C code? Maybe a special typedef, or a flag to clang?

I know I can do casts in LLVM IR, but I'm looking for something I can do on the C side so I don't have to tweak the IR by hand.

Comment: If you care about the efficiency here, you will need to gather the bits into a single variable yourself.  I'd push that worry off a bit though until everything else is working.

Comment: How many C sources have you checked to see if at least one of them uses the `i1` type? I'd try several source files from different projects, PC and embedded, for different targets, just as a quick experiment. Perhaps the type appears just when a condition is about to be checked.

Comment: @thebusybee that's a good approach. Clang does create `i1` values when a condition is about to be checked, but I still haven't found a way to write C code such that a value in a variable or field is an `i1`. I'm leaning toward not using `i1` in the LLVM representation of any datatypes in my language, but sticking with `i8` for bools and tags, though I lose the immediacy of checking that value directly in a branch. LLVM can probably optimize some compare instructions out anyway.

Comment: And since LLVM is designed to be processor-independent there might be a use case for variables of `i1` with machines that can address single bits. Although I don't know enough of 32-bit architectures, I know that at least one 8-bit architecture does.

Comment: C supports bit fields IIRC, so you can use bit fields for some things. In your case I'd also use a combination or IR-level shims and unit tests, to make sure that what Clang generates matches what your language expects.